# Merge and interact between two graphs in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

There is way for merge two graphs `G` and `H` side by side or even interact between them after computing layout? I need same spring look for single and merged graph.

```
G = nx.Graph() pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, edge_color=colors, **options, node_color=colors_nodes, width=widths)
H = nx.Graph()
pos2 = nx.spring_layout(H)
nx.draw_networkx(H, pos2, edge_color=colors, **options, node_color=colors_nodes, width=widths)
```

The final look should be like this [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6muX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would be looking for the [`disjoint_union`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.disjoint_union.html) function or the [`union`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.disjoint_union.html) depending upon your use case and the nature of your graphs' nodes being distinct integers or not

Example would be:

```py
 G = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)])
 H = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2)])
 I = nx.union(G, H, rename=("G", "H"))
 J = nx.Graph(I)
 nx.draw_networkx(J, pos, edge_color=colors, **options, node_color=colors_nodes, width=widths)
```

Comment: I don't mention this previously but graphs haven't equal nodes, edges amount so this two functions don't work.